# Wordpress menu not aligning horizontal even with custom class css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am having trouble aligning my wordpress menu on my custom designed theme. I am using a bootstrap 3 framework and I cannot get the menu to display inline although I have the correct css to list anything with the css class of menu-nav inlined. please check out the page is my css wrong or is there something I have to do to wordpress?

http://smeprintinganddesign.net

Heres my custom CSS so far

```
body{
    color: black;
}

menu-nav {
    position: relative;

    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline !important;
    line-height: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav js-nav-add-active-class">
          <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/basket/">Basket</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/checkout/">Checkout</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-21"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/my-account/">My Account</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-18"><a href="http://www.smeprintinganddesign.net/shop/">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hi your menu is nested one layer deep in another unordered list so it's not getting the bootstrap classes applied to it. Remove the inner ul and li and div class menu and it works. See the updated menu code above.

What you may have to do is remove the divs added "before" and "after" by the WordPress function that runs the menu in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php. More here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in your css file and your menu will be aligned.

```
.navbar-nav li a {
line-height: 60px;
padding-top: 0px;
```

}